# Can't save my metabox data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to save some data but i can't. The problem is that the data saved is not that i expect but is an empty array.

This is the code. Please, what's the problem?...i'm going mad!

PS: I'm learning PHP so maybe this is a stupid question...Is there a way to control the variable $_POST before it's send?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: nw_Page_Gallery


*/


class NW_mb{

    var $post_meta = array("image1","image2");
    var $id;


    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function add_Box(){

        add_meta_box("nw_meta_box","Sfondo pagina",array($this, 'add_html'),"page");

    }

    public function add_Html($post){

        $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "nw_meta_boxes");
        $this->id = $post->ID;


        print_r($post_meta);

        ?>

        <label>Indirizzo immagine</label>
        <input type="text" id="nw_image1" name="nw_image1" value="<?php echo $post_meta[0] ?>" />

        <label>Indirizzo immagine</label>
        <input type="text" id="nw_image2" name="nw_image2" value="<?php echo $post_meta[1] ?>" />

        <label>Indirizzo immagine</label>
        <input type="text" id="nw_image3" name="nw_image3" value="<?php echo $post_meta[2] ?>" />

        <label>Indirizzo immagine</label>
        <input type="text" id="nw_image4" name="nw_image4" value="<?php echo $post_meta[3] ?>" />

        <label>Indirizzo immagine</label>
        <input type="text" id="nw_image5" name="nw_image5" value="<?php echo $post_meta[4] ?>" />


        <?

    }

    public function save_Box(){

        $boxes = array(
            isset($_POST['nw_image1']),
            isset($_POST['nw_image2']),
            isset($_POST['nw_image3']),
            isset($_POST['nw_image4']),
            isset($_POST['nw_image5'])
        );

        update_post_meta($this->id, 'nw_meta_boxes', $boxes);


    }

}




add_action("add_meta_boxes", function(){
    $NW_mb_istance = new NW_mb;

    $NW_mb_istance->add_Box();
});

add_action("save_post", array($NW_mb_istance,"save_Box"));
```

Comment: Your problem is with scope and when your instantiation occurs. [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class) should help you get started in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a particolar piece of code i have to check? I think that the error is in add_action(save_post... etc